# how to get Flutter firebase currentUser data?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I have a flutter web app connected to firebase I use provider to authenticate user. In the firebase data base I have 'user' collection and inside it documents with the users id (they are stored from another app)
My current fluuterweb app need to read this data, I used provider and user class but I only can access first documents.

this is the main file code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthenticationService>(
          create: (_) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
        ),
        StreamProvider<User>(
          create: (context) =>
              context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
        ),
        ProxyProvider<User, CollectionReference>(
            update: (_, user, __) => linksCollection(user?.uid)),
        ProxyProvider<User, Stream<List<UserChannelLink>>>(
          update: (_, user, __) => userLinks(linksCollection(user?.uid)),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => AuthenticationWrapper(),
          '/settings': (context) => SettingsPage(),
        },
        onUnknownRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => NotFoundPage(routeName: settings.name),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  userLinks(CollectionReference linksCollection) {
    return linksCollection.snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.docs
          .map((doc) => UserChannelLink.fromDocument(doc))
          .toList();
    });
  }

  CollectionReference linksCollection(String userId) =>
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users/');
}
```

and here the page where I need to show my data (channel name and logo in the appbar):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _channelData = Provider.of<Stream<List<UserChannelLink>>>(context);

    return StreamProvider<List<UserChannelLink>>(
        create: (_) => _channelData,
        child: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            final _channelData = Provider.of<List<UserChannelLink>>(context);
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Center(child: Text('Timytime')),
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
                actions: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 60,
                      width: 60,
                      child: Image.network(_channelData.first.channelName),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Text(_channelData.first.channelName),
                  ),
```

and here is the user class:

```
 factory UserChannelLink.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot data) {
    return UserChannelLink(
      id: data.data()['id'],
      logoLink: data.data()['logoLink'],
      genre: data.data()['genre'],
      channelName: data.data()['channelName'],
    );
  }
```